# Audit.Net MVC - How to solve the NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, audit.net

We have been using the Audit.Net package in our system. It is very useful!
However, we have run into an error when trying to implement it for a different environment/client. The auditing does work in a different Controller class, but in this one we get the error.

I think we are just missing something simple.
[image]

Can anyone help us in the right direction?

This is the full method:

[image]

Comment: The error indicates that `this.GetCurrentAuditScope()` is null. The method `GetCurrentAuditScope()` is returning null and that's what's causing the `NullReferenceException`.The problem is there.

Comment: Please add code and errors as text to the question, instead of using images of text.

Comment: @phuzi, The code is not on my machine. These are the screenprints my colleague sent me. I can't get access to the environment due to red-tape and my country's current lockdown.

Comment: @NicodeOry yes, but why is the AuditScope (that should be returned by GetCurrentAuditScope) null? I thought the AuditScope is created automatically in Audit.MVC?

Comment: Share at least the stack trace, otherwise we can only guess... Is that method `UpdateAssesmentRequest` the action method on the controller? I don't think so. You have to decorate the MVC Action Method (or the controller) with the `[Audit]` attribute.

Comment: @thepirat000, Aha! Yes that must be it! I'll ask my colleague to put it on the action methods. UpdateAssessmentRequest seems like a auxiliary method.

Comment: If your colleague can send you screen shots, can't they send you the text?!

Comment: @phuzi, sure, but they were probably asleep. I work as a contractor for the company, so often I work late at night or early in the morning, - whenever it suits me. I would have asked him for the text this morning, but then I saw thepirat000's comment and could conclude what the problem was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the method `UpdateAssesmentRequest` is not the *action method* on the controller, but an auxiliary method.

[Audit.MVC](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.Mvc/README.md) needs the action method (or the controller class) to be decorated with `[Audit]` action filter attribute.

So you have to decorate your MVC Action Method with the `[Audit]` attribute, not the auxiliary method. Then you should be able to get the `AuditScope` from any controller method.

Note the `GetCurrentAuditScope` method tries to get the current audit scope from the HttpContext's items collection, like this:

```cs
httpContext?.Items["__private_AuditScope__"] as AuditScope
```

[source code](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/62c0acd580f9aa7a33d79b97b86501bd8a73d1c4/src/Audit.Mvc/AuditAttribute.Core.cs#L342)